# Android - Custom view in fragment not working in onResume()

Tags: android, android-view, android-lifecycle

I have created a custom view to draw a line on the screen. This view is included in a fragment's xml layout and retrieved like the following in the fragment's `onCreateView` method:

```
MyCustomView mMyCustomView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate view
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    mMyCustomView = (MyCustomView) v.findViewById(R.id.my_custom_view);
    ...
}
```

When I pass the `mMyCustomView` variable to a custom listener in the fragment's `onCreateView` method and call something like `mMyCustomView.drawLine` in the listener class everything works fine.

When I call `mMyCustomView.drawLine` in the fragment's `onResume()` method, however, nothing happens, though it is the same variable and method.

The only reason I could think of is that the listener calls the method when the user interacts with the fragment, which is even later than the `onResume()` is called, as far as the lifecycle is concerned. However, within the fragment I cannot call the method any later than in `onResume()` AFAIK.

**EDIT 1**:

This is what my custom view looks like:

```
public class ConnectionLinesView extends View {
// Class variables
Paint mPaint = new Paint(); // Paint to apply to lines
ArrayList<float[]> mLines = new ArrayList<float[]>(); // Array to store the lines


public ConnectionLinesView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
}


public ConnectionLinesView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
    super(context, attrs);

    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
}


public ConnectionLinesView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
}


protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    // If lines were already added, draw them
    if(!mLines.isEmpty()){
        for(float[] line : mLines){
            canvas.drawLine(line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], mPaint);
        }
    }

}


// Method to add a line to the view
public void addLine(View v1, View v2) {
    float[] line = new float[4];
    line[0] = v1.getX() + v1.getWidth()/2;
    line[1] = v1.getY() + v1.getHeight()/2;
    line[2] = v2.getX() + v2.getWidth()/2;
    line[3] = v2.getY() + v2.getHeight()/2;

    mLines.add(line);
    this.invalidate();
}


public void removeLines() {
    mLines.clear();
    this.invalidate();
}

}
```

When I call addLine(...) in `onResume()`, the line is not drawn, even though the inside of the for loop in the `onDraw()` method is reached. When I add another line later in the listener class (which responds to some user interaction), the both lines are drawn on the canvas. Somehow the `canvas.drawLine()` doesn't work in the `onResume()` of the view's parent fragment.

**EDIT 2**:

I have added a handler, that calls the custom view's `invalidate` method repeatedly after the fragment has been added to the layout of the parent activity. The line still doesn't get drawn!

Comment: I've also tried calling the drawLine method in the `onFocusChanged` method of a `onFocusChangeListener`, but this didn't work either. Doesn't anyone have a clue?

Comment: Which listener is the one you mentioned? Can you paste the code? And also, what is drawLine doing exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I solved the problem by creating a handler, which calls the `addLine` method after 50 milliseconds after the fragment has been added. A pretty dirty solution, but it works...